# SoX doesn't work with Opus Audio files

Tags: audio, type-conversion, ogg, sox, opus

I am recording input microphone from a web page with WebRTC and process it through SoX.

Problem is, Firefox recordings are in Opus Audio format (according to VLC media informations), in an Ogg container, and SoX doesn't like it : 
`` /opt/local/bin/sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `/Users/[...]/public/audio/7a0d13a501.ogg': Input not an Ogg Vorbis audio stream ``

Is there a way to make it work with SoX?
Or should I use another command-line audio tool?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ended up doing this (either works, don't know which is the fastest):

`opusdec --force-wav file.ogg - | sox - file.mp3`

or

`sox "|opusdec --force-wav file.ogg -" file.mp3`

Comment: To use the opusdec option opus-tool should be installed:                       `sudo apt-get install opus-tools`

Comment: I haven't got the piping to work well yet, but using opusdec and then sox worked for me as well. On OSX brew allows you to install sox with opus support, so the additional step isn't necessary. I am guessing we would need to manually recompile sox with an opus option to get that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify `-t opus` when running sox

```
    sox -t opus file.ogg out.wav
```

Comment: I don't know what package you have, but the Debian package fails with: `sox FAIL formats: no handler for given file type 'opus'`

Comment: I tested it on mac OS (seems like as well as @ryancey) with latest sox from brew

Answer (score 0):

sox -t opus file.ogg out.wav works fine and not sure why opus is not part of the build on debian.

https://github.com/chirlu/sox/blob/master/INSTALL

Don't trust the distro build yourself as sox rox :)